Was almond flour available in common grocery stores of the 1970s?
The title really says it all, so this body just explains why I'm asking (in case it inspires frame challenges or useful comments). I grew up in the 1970s in a small, Pennsylvania farming community with some (but not a lot) of Amish and Pennsylvania Dutch influence.  I am an utter novice at baking.
The cutout Christmas sugar cookies I had back then had a unique flavor and texture I haven't had since. I won't try to describe it.  But I know it wasn't just one person's recipe. I had those cookies at school parties, Scout meetings, and who knows where else for years. Then, some time in the 1980s, I realized I hadn't had them for years. And I haven't had anything like them since. The were basically rolled and cutout sugar cookies; soft, not especially buttery, and less than a quarter inch thick. I don't think they had a lot of leavening. There were on the dense side and not bready or cakey.
I've been looking for recipes that might have that "special something" (other than common sugar cookie ingredients). Almond extract is definitely part of the flavor, but somethig is missing. The closest I've found is lightly toasted almond flour.  That's getting closer to what I remember, but I'm not there yet.
So before I start experimenting with different almond flour recipes, I want to check that I'm not "baking" up the wrong tree. Almond flour seems kind of specialized. I  had certainly never heard of it as a kid. And for a town where tacos, bagels, and even rice were seen as "exotic," I wonder if it was even available in common grocery stores of that era.
Was it? I understand the answer might vary with location and the size of the town. I understand it was probably available at niche stores in metropolitan areas. So the question could be rephrased, "Was it readily available all over the place where only the smallest stores probably wouldn't have had it?"

If you've only experimented with almond flour recipes so far, I'd suggest you also experiment with marzipan-based recipes, for example German Marzipanheidesand sounds a lot like what you describe. It could also be a standard almond cookie recipe, if people were preparing their own almond meal and either using a given proportion of bitter to sweet almonds, or simply using good quality home grown almonds, as opposed to the stuff that's sold ubiquitously nowadays.

You don’t need to buy almond flour  - when I was a kid, we’d buy whole hazelnuts etc. (they store better, too), then grind them fresh with a hand-cranked nut mill. The kind with a horizontal grating drum. And these ground nuts definitely went into whatever baked goods were up next, including macaroons and cakes.

In the Netherlands I've seen almond flour until a few years ago (but I've not been looking hard in the past, I have to admit). What IS common here in the baking supplies section of grocery stores is almond shavings (very thinly sliced almonds) and that's pretty common in cookies.

I don't remember seeing almond flour when growing up, but almond paste used to be easily available in grocery stores in Maryland, which is only one state away  (almond paste is similar to marzipan, but typically used as an ingredient in other recipes)

Best I recall (rural Northeastern USA), you had to put your almonds in the blender* yourself (and then sift out the big chunks to run through again,) at that point in time unless you were ordering in from some specialty supplier.
* Food processors might have existed, but were not remotely common, either.

when we crushed nuts it wasn't with a blender (wish we'd have one) but by putting the (shelled) nuts between two tea towels and then going at them with a rolling pin until they had the size range we needed :)
